# ¿Cómo recorrer un array bidimensional en PHP?

Tags: php, html

Tengo un array compuesto por array´s y no se como recorrer los valores de los array internos para hacer una comprobacion. Supongamos que en un input escribo "admin1" como puedo recorrer los valores del array.

```
$arrayRoles = array(
    array("admin1", "admin1", "administrador"),
    array("prof1", "prof1", "profesor"),
    array("alum1", "alum1", "alumno")
);

function checkUser($array, $usu) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $array; $i++) {
        for ($i = 0; $i <=3; $i++){
        if $usu == 'valor de el array'{
                //Retorna true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$arrayRoles = array(
    array("admin1", "admin1", "administrador"),
    array("prof1", "prof1", "profesor"),
    array("alum1", "alum1", "alumno")
);

function checkUser($array, $usu) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++) {
        for ($j = 0; $j < sizeof($array[0]); $j++){
            if ($usu == $array[$i][$j]){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Puedes usar la función [`count`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.count.php), la cual devuelve la cantidad de elementos en el arreglo.

Ejemplo:

```
<?php

$arrayRoles = array(
    array("admin1", "admin1", "administrador"),
    array("prof1", "prof1", "profesor"),
    array("alum1", "alum1", "alumno")
);

function checkUser($array, $usu) {

    $total = count($array);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
        for ($j = 0; $j <=3; $j++){
            if ($usu == $array[$i][$j]) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: gracias por la ayuda ;D

Answer (score 3):

Personalmente, creo que utilizando el bucle `foreach` es mucho más visual:

```
$arrayRoles = array(
    array("admin1", "admin1", "administrador"),
    array("prof1", "prof1", "profesor"),
    array("alum1", "alum1", "alumno")
);

function checkUser($array, $usu) {
    foreach($array as $arrayInterno){
       //En $array tendremos cada uno de los arrays internos
       foreach($arrayInterno as $palabra){
          //En $palabra tendremos cada uno de los valores de cada array interno
          if($palabra == $usu){
             //Tu código
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: aunque tu codigo se ve que funciona bien, es muy confuso al recibir $array y recorrar $arrayRoles

Comment: @JackNavaRow He editado la respuesta. Espero que ahora se entienda claro.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, me vino genial

Answer (score 2):

Las respuestas están bien si sabes en cual dimensión quieres buscar.

Ejemplo.. si en tu array existiera un valor en el primer *vector* no lo encontraría:

```
$array = array('superadmin', // <= Este quedaría fuera de la búsqueda
  array( "admin1", "admin1", "administrador" ),
  array( "prof1", "prof1", "profesor" ),
  array( "alum1", "alum1", "alumno" )
);

function checkUser($usu, $array) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++) {
        for ($j = 0; $j < sizeof($array[0]); $j++){
            if ($usu == $array[$i][$j]){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}

var_dump( checkUser( 'superadmin', $array ) ); // Resultado: NULL
```

<kbd>[Ver demo 1](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3945e703de0bc8c2b51de7f1e431cd747331749f)</kbd>

Así que te daré otra solución más flexible y sin tener que preocuparse cuantas *dimensiones* tenga el array.

La rueda ya está inventada hace mucho.. igual que la próxima función:

[Ver código original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128323/in-array-and-multidimensional-array/4128377#4128377)

```
// Un vector
$dim_1 = array( "admin1", "admin1", "administrador", 
                "prof1", "prof1", "profesor", 
                "alum1", "alum1", "alumno" );

// Dos vectores
$dim_2 = array( array("admin1", "admin1", "administrador"),
                array("prof1", "prof1", "profesor"),
                array("alum1", "alum1", "alumno") );

// Tres vectores
$dim_3 = array( array("admin1", "admin1", "administrador"),
                array("prof1", "prof1", "profesor", 
                    array("alum1", "alum1", "alumno") ) );


function in_array_r( $buscar, $array, $estricto = false ) {

  foreach ( $array as $item ) {

        if ( ( $estricto ? $item === $buscar : $item == $buscar) ||
           ( is_array( $item ) && in_array_r( $buscar, $item, $estricto ) ) ) {

            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var_dump( in_array_r( 'alumno', $dim_1 ) ); // Resultado: true
var_dump( in_array_r( 'alumno', $dim_2 ) ); // Resultado: true
var_dump( in_array_r( 'alumno', $dim_3 ) ); // Resultado: true
```

<kbd>[Ver demo 2](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/eecc872d805d57cf2b4d925b9116ccd244b3adef)</kbd>

**Explicación de la función:**

Trabaja con la función [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php), pero este puede comprobar solo lo que están en el mismo *vector*, ósea no puede saber que valores hay en los otros *vectores*.

Entonces tenemos una [función recursiva](http://php.net/manual/es/functions.user-defined.php#example-175), como indica ya el nombre *recursiva*, hace que llama tantas veces la misma función hasta que encuentre el valor (`true`) **O** termina de pasar todos los *vectores* y termina con un resultado `false`.